# Get and use class from calling object

Tags: java, abstract

Let us say that we have in abstract class the following method.

```
public Object Foo() {
    [X] someObject;

    /* some operations*/

    return someObject;
}
```

What I want is that to get and use the class of the calling object from a class extended of the method over. The [X] represent (psuedo code) the object of the calling class. How can I achive to init *someObject* with the class of the object that called Foo()?

**EDIT:**
I want to get the class that called that method. And then use that class to create a new object of it. And the response that I got is that it is ***imposible*** without a refernce.

Simply said is it imposible to substituting [X] with the class that called the method?

Comment: You're using `X` as a type name, but you say that it represents an object. It's unclear to me what you want to do.

Comment: I am sorry X represent pseudo code. Instead of X I would want the class of the object calling the method.

Comment: If you're saying that you want the to get the class that called that method, it's not really possible unless you have a reference.

Comment: @CoderMusgrove Okay too bad.

Comment: _The X represent (psuedo code) the object of the calling class._ I still don't understand. What if your `clone` method was invoked from a `static` method? What do you need such a value for anyway?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It would be nice to give the clone the correct class instead of an super class.

Comment: Your explanation of what you're trying to do doesn't make any sense. We can't really help unless you edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Like @CoderMusgrove said I want the to get the class that called that method. And the use that class to create a new object of it.

Comment: What does that have to do with `clone`? That's not what `clone` does.

Comment: This sounds like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), please tell us about what you actually want to do.

Comment: "Simply said is it imposible to substituting [X] with the class that called the method?" I can not manage do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is exactly what you want, but you can look at the current Thread's [stack trace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace--). The second item in the array will be the caller. The problem is that the [class name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#getClassName--) may be a super class of the actual class calling you.

Comment: This would be a completely insane way to create objects.

Comment: I am not suggesting this is a good idea. It is simply a (partial) answer to the question posed.